# Reversion of power series

Tags: power-series, inverse

So, I just heard about this method. How does one determine the coefficients, and what is it used for?

For example, given $$ y = x - \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^5}{120} + O(x^7)$$ reversion would give a series for $x$ in terms of $y$, correct? And then this expansion could be used to expand $y$ in ascending powers of itself?

Comment: Yes, I know that my example was the Taylor series for $\sin{x}$ ~ I must be missing something on that page!

Comment: Yes generally this is messy, see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html. You should compute coefficients for the inverse by hand usually to first or second order

Comment: "And then this expansion could be used to expand y in ascending powers of itself?" Yes it could, and it would yield the expansion $y=y+O(y^n)$ for every $n\geqslant2$.

Comment: Series reversion: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/584866/algorithm-for-reversion-of-power-series

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think how you go about inverting the series is to first do this:

$$x = y + \frac{x^3}{6} - \frac{x^5}{120} - O(x^7),$$

so that

$$x = y + \frac{1}{6}(y + \frac{x^3}{6} - \frac{x^5}{120} - O(x^7))^3 - 
 \frac{1}{120}(y + \frac{x^3}{6} - \frac{x^5}{120} - O(x^7))^5 + O(y^7)$$

Then gather the terms of order less than $y^7$ and discard those $y^7$ and higher.  If you still have terms with powers of $x$ that are multiplied by powers of $y$ with order less than $y^7$, substitute the first expression again until you don't.