# How to get inverse function(series) of a series that with unknown power

Tags: power-series, inverse-function, inverse-function-theorem

I am facing a problem in my research:
If a series takes form of:
$$
y=a_1x^{n_1}+a_2x^{n_2}+\cdots+a_jx^{n_j}+\cdots
$$
How to get its inverse function(series)?

Maybe its inverse series takes form of:
$$
x=b_1y^{m_1}+b_2y^{m_2}+\cdots+b_jy^{m_3}+\cdots
$$

$n_1,n_2,\cdots,m_1,m_2,\cdots$ are arbitrary rationals, arbitrary reals but not integers completely. Actually, it takes form of
$$
n_i(or\ m_i)=3l_iz+k_i
$$
where $l_i$ and $k_i$ are arbitrary positive integers but z is arbitrary reals.

But I don't know how to get it. At least I want to get the first few terms.

Comment: Could you please specify what are the exponents $n_1,n_2,...$? Are they (increasing/decreasing?) integers, rationals with fixed denominator, arbitrary rationals, arbitrary reals?

Comment: The search term is *reversion of series*. There have been questions about this here before, e.g., https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/625195/reversion-of-power-series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.) Rational exponents**

Transform your series $y$ of $x$ to a *power series* $z$ of $t$ by substituting $x\to t^p$, where $p$ is the least common multiple of the denominators of $n_1,n_2,...\ $. Consider rule 4.2.19 on page 70 of [Abramowitz/Stegun 1970].

Transform $z$ by subtracting its constant term.

The inversion will be made by Lagrange inversion:
You can create the usual system of equations that is used for inverting power series and solve the system term by term. See e.g. [Chernoff 1947].

Example for your original series where all exponents are integer:

$$f(x)=a_1x^{n_1}+a_2x^{n_2}+\cdots+a_jx^{n_j}+\cdots$$

$$f^{-1}(y)=b_1y^{m_1}+b_2y^{m_2}+\cdots+b_jy^{m_3}+\cdots$$

$$f(f^{-1}(x))=x:$$

$$a_1\left(b_0+b_1x^{m_1}+b_2x^{m_2}+b_3x^{m_3}+\cdots\right)^{n_1}+a_2\left( b_0+b_1x^{m_1}+b_2x^{m_2}+b_3x^{m_3}+\cdots\right)^{n_2}+a_3\left(b_0+b_1x^{m_1}+b_2x^{m_2}+b_3x^{m_3}+\cdots\right)^{n_3}+\cdots=x$$

Expand this expression and collect all terms of the same degree of $x$. Solve the equation system successively for $m_1$, $m_2$ and so on.

Or apply one of the general formulas of [Lagrange inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem).

**2.) Real exponents**

Maybe the following helps:
[Loeb, D.: Series with general exponents. 1995](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9502216)

Maybe the [binomial theorem for real exponents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton%27s_generalized_binomial_theorem) together with [Xiao-Xiong Gan 2021] helps. Apply the equation from 1.), but now with real exponents.
$\ $

[Abramowitz/Stegun 1970] Abramowitz, M.; Stegun, I.: Handbook of Mathematical Functions with Formulas, Graphs, and Mathematical Tables. National Bureau of Standard 1970

[[Chernoff 1947] Chernoff, H.: A Note on the inversion of power series. Math. Comp. 2 (1947) 331-335](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1947-02-020/S0025-5718-1947-0022717-X/)

[Xiao-Xiong Gan 2021] Xiao-Xiong Gan: Formal Analysis. An Introduction. De Gruyter, 2021: 9 Formal series and general exponents. 9.4 The real exponents of formal power series

Comment: Thank you! I have read them. But the thing is, can these formulae work for the series which power is not integer?